# Create Event on Teams Channel Calendar from API application using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: graph, microsoft-teams

we are trying to create a calender event in teams channel, Please provide the api.

Comment: Please provide more information like what you have tried and if you are getting some error. If you have used [Create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and getting some error then please update the question accordingly

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft, The document which you have provided related to create event that is creating a event in mail calendar and group , But i would like to create the calendar event or scheduled event in "teams channel".Please provide me the api for teams channel.

Comment: Please give me the API call to postmessage as calender event in Teams channel.
like eg :
"attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "1637663012513",
                    "contentType": "meetingReference",
                    "contentUrl": null,
                    "content": "{\"exchangeId\":\"AAMkADAxM\"}",
                    "name": "Meeting invite",
                    "thumbnailUrl": null
                }
            ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently API to create event in team channel is not available. You can have a look at this available API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples but it also doesn't support to create event in channel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hunaid Hanfee-MSFT, 
So is there any road map to get this available

Comment: We have internal backlog item for it. As of ETA I don't have a exact date but it should get available in early quarters.

Comment: Hi Team, Can you please provide any update on this?

Comment: @lakshminarayana - We are checking with the engineering team. We will let you know once we have any update.

Comment: @lakshminarayana - Currently this feature is not supported. We don't have any exact ETA to share.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, Thanks for the update , So do we have any other approach to solve this events like eg, bot,sdk et.,,

Comment: @lakshminarayana - There is no other approach also for creating event in Teams channel.

Comment: Any update on this question, I am having the same exact requirement to create a channel calendar event using graph api?

Comment: Currently this feature is not supported. You can raise a feature request here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)